# Projetos Xcode com Images.xcassets

Tags: ios, xcode, iphone

Nos projetos iOS criados pelo Xcode, tem uma "pasta" chamada **Images.xcassets**, ou seja, um catálogo de assets do Xcode.

- Nesse catálogo, eu adiciono uma imagem para um `UIButton` por exemplo, e essa imagem eu sou obrigado a manter ela dentro do projeto? Ou somente no Images.xcassets?
- Dentro do Images.xcassets, quando adiciono uma imagem por exemplo, ela me apresenta o *overview*, que possui no caso três espaços, que são respectivamente 1x, 2x e 3x. Eu sou obrigado a definir todos os três para que a imagem apareça em um iPhone retina? Ou se eu definir somente no 1x ele vai aparecer em todos os outros dispositivos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O "arquivo" xcassets na verdade já é um diretório, se voce clicar em um item do xcassets com o botao direito e clicar em "Open in finder" voce verá o path em que a imagem está. Não precisa colocar outra referencia para ela no projeto.

Se voce não tiver as imagens 2x e 3x, a imagem mostrada será a 1x redimensionada para o tamanho da 2x ou 3x.

Comment: Lembrando, que a "indexação" das imagens feitas através do xcassets é feita através de JSON (o próprio xcode gera isso), fazendo com que os nomes das imagens não precisem ser os mesmos da imagem no xcassets. Ao amigo da pergunta, a melhor opção, é definir pelo menos a imagem 3x